# Guice dependency injection binding multiple classes to the same interface

Tags: java, dependency-injection, module, binding, guice

Base interface:

```
public interface Registry<E> {
    E method();
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
RegistryImpl<E> implements Registry<E> {

    @Inject
    RegistryImpl(...) {
    }

    @Override
    public E method() {
         (...)
    }

}
```

Used for binding the registry for data object A:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface CustomDataObjectARegistry {
}
```

Used for binding the registry for data object B:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface CustomDataObjectBRegistry {
}
```

I want to bind CustomDataObjectARegistry to `RegistryImpl<DataObjectA>` and CustomDataObjectBRegistry to `RegistryImpl<DataObjectB>` but have not been able to figure out the syntax.

```
bind(CustomDataObjectARegistry.class).to(new TypeLiteral<RegistryImpl<DataObjectA>>() {})
```

is giving me a "cannot resolve method to."

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is either:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Registry<DataObjectA>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<RegistryImpl<DataObjectA>>() {})
bind(new TypeLiteral<Registry<DataObjectB>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<RegistryImpl<DataObjectB>>() {})

//and then inject with generics:
Registry<DataObjectA> registryA;
Registry<DataObjectB> registryB;
```

or:

```
bind(Registry.class).annotatedWith(CustomDataObjectARegistry.class).to(new TypeLiteral<RegistryImpl<DataObjectA>>() {})
bind(Registry.class).annotatedWith(CustomDataObjectBRegistry.class).to(new TypeLiteral<RegistryImpl<DataObjectB>>() {})

//and then inject with annotations:
@CustomDataObjectARegistry Registry registryA;
@CustomDataObjectBRegistry Registry registryB;
```

basically you can use the full generic signature to differentiate, or you can use annotations, but you shouldn't need both.  I'd suggest differentiating via the generics.